# Would book reviews be a useful aspect of this site?

Tags: discussion, reviews

From time to time we ask about useful photography books or we reference them. Newcomers often need to know what books are a good guide to their photographic journey.

So it might be very useful to have a question in the form of:

*What is your considered opinion of book xxx by author yyy?*
*Please give your answer in the form of a full book review if you have it in your possession and you have read it.*
*Our guidelines for book reviews are as follows*

- .....
- .....

The different answers will constitute different reviews of the same book from different perspectives.

Answer (score 3):

Hmm. I can't say I am a fan of this.

1. It has the "infinite answers" problem in that everyone can have an opinion about a book, and hundreds of users could provide the answer.
2. There is no problem -- per [the FAQ](https://photo.stackexchange.com/faq)

   > "If your motivation for asking the question is “I would like to participate in a discussion about ______”, then you should not be asking here."

I think I would prefer for books to come up more naturally in the context of an *actual question* with a *real problem*. Citations to support an answer referencing a book make for a very strong answer!

Answer (score 0):

I like the idea and would at least like to see it tried. Answers would be, by definition, subjective, so that's something to be cautious about.

(And this would be a good example of subjective questions for which community wiki would not be appropriate, since the individual voice is important, and since good reviews are a reasonable amount of work and should be rewarded with reputation.)

On the other hand, I think this is a way in which we could *make the Internet a better place*, by having "peer reviewed" book reviews from a community of experts.

(It might be nice to ask people to only vote on answers if they've also read the book. No way to enforce that, of course.)

Comment: Oh, goodness -- reviewed reviews, with discussions in review on Meta. I'm having a flashback to the "GOD Over Djin" infinite recursion in *Gödel, Escher, Bach*. (I'm a Lisper, so that's a Good Thing™.)